# Solution for protocol downgrade attacks

Tags: tls

I am having protocol downgrade attacks on my website, and I have seen the solution to do TLS Fallback Signaling Cipher Suite Value (SCSV) to prevent protocol downgrade attacks.

[Refer link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-tls-downgrade-scsv/)

Can anyone suggest how can we implement the SCSV? I am really new to web servers and security, and would appreciate a step-by-step solution.

Comment: Hi djrecker, welcome to [security.se]. Can you please elaborate your question a bit, explain what you mean. What protocol, what kind of attack? How does SCSV solve this, why doesn't TLS? What exactly are you looking for, and include any background information and previous research you may have done... (I'd rather not close this unless necessary, so it doesn't go back to crypto.se).

Comment: Hi Avid, I am also new to this, i have added more information to the question posted, please see if that helps.

Comment: I have no clue how one might implement SCSV, but in the meantime you could require that connections use TLS rather than SSL.

Comment: when you say you "have protocol downgrade attacks" on your server what exactly do you mean?  For example have you been given a finding in a security audit?  If so, what is the finding you've been given?  Also it would help to know what web server you're using.

Comment: Assuming that you are using Apache: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406586/how-to-enable-tls-fallback-scsv-on-apache

Answer (score 1):

Both, the client and server need to support it to make it work. TLS Fallback SCSV is used as a signaling cipher suite (TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV, value 0x5600) during the handshake. All new browsers (clients) supports it. On the server, you will enable it by updating OpenSSL.

From https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20141015.txt:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1 users should upgrade to 1.0.1j
OpenSSL 1.0.0 users should upgrade to 1.0.0o
OpenSSL 0.9.8 users should upgrade to 0.9.8zc
```

Debian and other distributions are deploying backports of the TLS-FALLBACK-SCSV update on OpenSSL.

Also, upgrading alone is not sufficient. You have to disable SSLv2 and SSLv3.

Refereces:
https://alpacapowered.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/ssl-poodle-attack-what-is-this-scsv-thingy/ 
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL_MODE_SEND_FALLBACK_SCSV
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406586/how-to-enable-tls-fallback-scsv-on-apache